# SpringBoot - Timeout error when response takes more than 30 seconds

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am working on a Spring boot application where i have to throw an error when a response takes more than 30 seconds.

As I am using application.yml, I have tried

```
server:
  port: 8080
  session:
        timeout: 30
```

As it is not working, tried using application.properties - 
`server.session.timeout = 30`. its not working either.

Trying to find out how to throw system error on both conditions. i.e. when timeout occurs after system is idle and when response is taking more than 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 1.4 and later you can use the property server.connection-timeout.

```
server.connection-timeout= # Time that connectors wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default is used. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (that is, an infinite) timeout.
```

you can see common properties to customize spring boot default settings

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html